# How to use App Version in config.xml when performing a Pro.init

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm developing an Ionic Pro app. During the initialization of Ionic Pro in `app.module.ts`, I am required to provide an app version like so:

`Pro.init('<APP_ID_PLACEHOLDER>', {
  appVersion: 'APP_VERSION_PLACEHOLDER'
});`

However, instead of hard coding the app version in the `app.module.ts` file, I'd like to use the app version in `config.xml`.

Does anyone know how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this plugin? 
I think this can help you
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appversion